# How can I send an automated email to my Person Account contact?

Tags: workflow, email-alert, person-accounts

I have a Workflow Rule on the Opportunity object that sends an email to Users and the Owner which is fine.

I want to add an action to the Workflow Rule to email the associated Person Account email address. However, the Create Email Alert does not offer the Person Account as a recipient.

Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you can't. There have been requests for many years to Salesforce from the success community to allow Workflows to Send Alerts to Person Accounts as to no avail.

A workaround would be to create a custom email field and copy the primary Email field to this custom email field (with a WFR / Field update). The custom email field is available as a recipient to Workflow Email Alerts.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion. My alternative is Apex run from a Process Builder workflow. But having looked at this I'm heading back to your solution. I'll accept your answer if it gets me anywhere near a solution this morning. thanks, @Fred.

Comment: This is really annoying.

Comment: 5 years later and still not resolved.. Link to the 'official' workaround: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334427&type=1&mode=1